# html and javascript tokenizer for lucene elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I would like to tokenize html (not parse!) and javascript so that I can search the sourcecode we produce.

For example, a query of:

```
field:"jquery.1.11.min.js"
```

would return documents containing that.

Does anyone have information regarding a code tokenizer?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any code analyzers, per se.  Generally, if you want to index web content, you'dd use some other library to parse it and extract content, then analyze and index the extracted content.

But, looking for the shotgun approach, just chucking a bunch of raw code right into the index.  Analysis won't be perfect no matter how you go about it, but it's a approximate effort anyway.  I'dd probably go with [`PatternAnalyzer`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-analyzer.html), for a first pass.  I wouldn't even change the defaults.  The default, `\W+`, means your tokens will be consecutive sequences of letters, numbers and underscores, which is about what is generally used for identifiers.

So, if you have:

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.min.js"></script>
```

You wind up with tokens like:  `script`, `src`, `jquery`, `1`, `11`, `min`, `js`, `script`

This would be most useful for searching phrases, probably.  So, for the search you indicated, you'll be using the same analysis, and be searching for a phrase of five consecutive terms:  `jquery`, `1`, `11`, `min`, `js`.  Which seems reasonable enough.

There are some significant weaknesses, of course.  It would be impossible to differentiate between `2.11`, `2*11` and `2+11`, for instance.  Something to bear in mind.